# Slicknav: how to close menu when clicking outside

Tags: jquery, mobile, slicknav

I am using the [SlickNav jQuery plugin](http://slicknav.com/), but it seems that auto-closing the menu on blur or lost focus is not set by default and there is no setting for it.

I thought it was just a simple call like this:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //close menu on lost focus
    $('.js .slicknav_menu').focusout(function(event){
     $(this).slicknav('close');
    });  
  });
 </script>
```

But this doesn't do anything. How do I close the menu when clicking outside of the menu?

Comment: Could you please share your complete code?

Comment: I don't know what other code you need, but I put a link to the plugin if you're unfamiliar with it.

Comment: This solution works for me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658550/make-slicknav-menu-close-when-outside-click-on-ios-devices/29677052#29677052

Answer (score 1):

I referred the site that you mentioned in your question. Tried the first example given in the site. (HTML code of which is given below)

HTML -

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#features">Features</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#usage">Usage Instructions</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#examples">Examples</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://github.com">View on Github</a></li>
</ul>
```

I saw menu was not closing by default on lost focus event. 
Below code worked to achieve the same.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //close menu on lost focus
    $('.slicknav_menu').focusout(function(event){
        $('#menu').slicknav('close'); //Here 'menu' is the id of ul.
    });  
  });
```

Comment: This is generally what I had before and it's still not working. This is what I have now, source files locations checks out fine:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wukdv

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this.
This works also on mobiles.

```
$(window).on("touchstart", function(e) {
    var container = $("#menu");
if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
{
    $('#menu').slicknav('close');
}
});
```