# Make Slicknav menu close when outside click on IOS devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, menu, focusout

I'm using the Slicknav mobile menu script: http://slicknav.com/

And it's working great except I can't figure out how to get it to close when one clicks outside of the menu on ios devices. It closes fine when clicking outside when I test it on desktop and Android, but on my Ipad it's not working. Here's the current code. Any insight? Thank you!

```
<script src="slicknav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.menu').slicknav({
label:'',
closeOnClick:true
});
$('.slicknav_menu').focusout(function(event){
$('.menu').slicknav('close');
});
});
</script>


<nav>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Link2</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: So I assume closeOnClick option is not cutting it and the piece of code after it is your attempt? `$('.slicknav_menu').focusout(function(event){
$('.menu').slicknav('close');
});
});` Also, this is probably a browser issue and has nothing to do with Ipad or Android. What is your browser that you use on Ipad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my site the right menu uses slicknav. It closes fine when i click outside on iOS thanks to this code. Demonstration : http://www.crealisationweb.fr

Replace this:

```
$('.slicknav_menu').focusout(function(event){
    $('.menu').slicknav('close');
});
```

With this :

```
$("div, html").on("click", function (event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).hasClass(".menu a") && 
    !$(event.target).hasClass("ul.slicknav_nav li a") && 
    !$(event.target).hasClass("slicknav_menutxt") && 
    !$(event.target).hasClass("slicknav_icon") && 
    !$(event.target).hasClass("slicknav_icon-bar") &&
    !$(event.target).hasClass("slicknav_btn")) {   
        $(".menu").slicknav('close'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I used something like this

```
$(window).on("touchstart", function(e) {
    var container = $("#menu");
if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
{
    $('#menu').slicknav('close');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember creating my first mobile website and this issue killed so much time. iOS has a known issue with `:hover` state when clicked.

Read up [here](http://blog.0100.tv/2010/05/fixing-the-hover-event-on-the-ipadiphoneipod/) - it should fix your issue.